# TypeScript: object not assignable to type even after narrowing

Tags: typescript

I have a function that receives an object and narrows it to check that it contains a specified property, `foo`, of a specific type, `string`.

Inside the narrowed branch I expect `input` to be assignable to `ObjectWithFooStringProp`, but it is not for some reason. Why is this?

```
type DictionaryLike = {
    [index: string]: unknown;
};

type ObjectWithFooStringProp = {
    foo: string;
};

const getObjectWithFooStringProp = (
    input: DictionaryLike,
): ObjectWithFooStringProp | null => {
    if (typeof input.foo === 'string') {
        input.foo; // Type is `string` ✅

        // Unexpected error ❌
        // Property 'foo' is missing in type 'DictionaryLike' but required in type 'ObjectWithFooStringProp'.
        return input;

        // Workaround:
        // return { foo: input.foo };
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

I have mentioned a workaround in the example above, however I have a real world use case where this workaround is not possible, so I am keen to get to the bottom of why TypeScript is behaving in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guards generally impact the type of the property they are applied not the whole object. A notable exception to this is discriminated unions for which the check on the descriminant property does change the type of the containing object. But in your care we don't have a discriminated union, so the check does not actually have any impact on `input`.

The only work around is to use a custom type guard to change the type of `input` after the check:

```
type DictionaryLike = {
    [index: string]: unknown;
};

type ObjectWithFooStringProp = {
    foo: string;
};
function hasStringProp<K extends string>(o: DictionaryLike, key: K) : o is Record<K, string>{
    return typeof o[key] === 'string';
}
const getObjectWithFooStringProp = (
    input: DictionaryLike,
): ObjectWithFooStringProp | null => {
    if (hasStringProp(input, 'foo')) {
        input.foo; // Type is `string` ✅

        // ok now
        return input;

        // Workaround:
        // return { foo: input.foo };
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitReturns=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgY2HA9gOwIYCcQBk4DW0AvFAN4BQU1UA2nGgCYQAeAXFAM7BYMDmAXQ4BXNATQoA7mgDcFAL5yKoSFADyAIwBWEJAHU4wABYAxFCgDKPfgAUsKMFFKUaUAGbmO3Xmj5zFFG6iSKhoUEYYnFY+fHYOADwA0lCswBBMnFzWvgB8ABQoHPAh6Nh4hBAANFBEIByJAJRQHChQcJkASrooWIxJ1d78OS40WBDAwlhhKhAoblAotLUCTsSkAOSDvuv+FAjo3FB845o6+oam5tG29o6keVQ0DGDCwEWIyKU4+ESVFA0cU66YAGYxmSzZWK3KAAHygaGEABtEU4cuRHtQ4PM8hEopC4mA8s9XtV1h4UOsGk0Rq5MWgXsAAHTkmRQAD0bKgABVwNB2lAAAZbPgCqCAUHIKBjaRyFgR4VIpa4xhMpm16a8lLSaDK9D0CNgUKJGGxFdrOcrJmEyO5PGqGczzFAAq55ClEZxoDTaRbVQjkXIXQo5EA)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a proposal to fix this in TypeScript so that the object type itself is also changed? If not then perhaps I will file one. I was deliberately trying to avoid using user-defined type guards here because of another design limitation in TypeScript: user-defined type guards have no type checking whatsoever. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29980.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Not really aware of such a proposal. Doesn't mean one does not exist. I know was an issue around narrowing `object` or `unknown` using type guards, but can't find it right now

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39256

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this doesn't work, but for the time being, you can use a dedicated type-guard which narrows the type correctly.

```
type DictionaryLike = {
    [index: string]: unknown;
};

type ObjectWithFooStringProp = {
    foo: string;
};

const isObjectWithFooStringProp = (input: DictionaryLike): input is ObjectWithFooStringProp =>
  typeof input.foo === 'string'

const getObjectWithFooStringProp = (
    input: DictionaryLike,
): ObjectWithFooStringProp | null => {
    if (isObjectWithFooStringProp(input)) {
        return input;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey, small world! :-) I was deliberately trying to avoid using user-defined type guards here because of a design limitation in TypeScript: user-defined type guards have no type checking whatsoever. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29980. However that's not to say this answer is wrong, just it doesn't quite fit my requirements. I'm sure it will help many people who come across this though. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can take advantage of type casting by using `return <ObjectWithFooStringProp>input;`

```js
type DictionaryLike = {
    [key: string]: unknown
}

type ObjectWithFooStringProp = {
    foo: string
}

const getObjectWithFooStringProp = (
    input: DictionaryLike
): ObjectWithFooStringProp | null => {
    if (typeof input.foo === 'string') {
        input.foo // Type is `string` ✅

        // No error ✅
        return <ObjectWithFooStringProp>input

        // Workaround:
        // return { foo: input.foo };
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the type cast loses some type checking.